# MVC 5 Entity Frame work display name not allowing to enter ten digit number giving error "Value is not valid for"?

Tags: entity-framework, validation, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

i have this property in my entity class,

```
[Display(Name = "Phone", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
public Nullable<int> Phone { get; set; }
```

i enter ten digit number it gives me error

```
"The value '5698452136' is not valid for"
```

if i enter 9 digits than ok

i have not apply any validation just display name according to language.

But id i remove Display property it works fine. why it is giving me validation error ?

EDITED:

Sorry my mistake on my required attribute it is giving this error,

```
 [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource),
          ErrorMessageResourceName = "PhoneRequired")]
```

after adding above required i am getting error as i mentioned above and works fine if i remove it

Hopes for your suggestions

Hopes for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change type from `int` to `long` as max value for integer is 2,147,483,647 and you are trying to pass 5,698,452,136 which exceeds the upper boundary.

```
[Display(Name = "Phone", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource),
          ErrorMessageResourceName = "PhoneRequired")]
public Nullable<long> Phone { get; set; }
```